# CMake and using git-submodule for dependence projects

Tags: cmake, git-submodules

Consider the following three projects.

`ProjectA` does not have any dependencies and its `CMakeLists.txt` at top level is like the following,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(A CXX)
add_library(a ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/liba.cpp)
```

`ProjectB` depend on `ProjectA`, and I add `ProjectA` as a git-submodule, so its structure will be like below,

- `ProjectB`

  - `CMakeLists.txt`
  - `libb.cpp`
  - `ProjectA` (git submodule)

    - `CMakeLists.txt`
    - `liba.cpp`

and `ProjectB`'s `CMakeLists.txt` look like the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(B CXX)
add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
add_library(b ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libb.cpp)
target_link_libraries(b a)
```

So far it is alright.

Now let's say it comes a `ProjectC`. It depends on both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`. And let's assume that I am not aware that `ProjectB` depends on `ProjectA` already (e.g., I did not create the two before. Or think that `ProjectC` actually have many dependencies and I shall not be forced to figure out an exact dependency tree among them).

Anyway, I add both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` as git submodules in `ProjectC`. So it has the following structure,

- `ProjectC`

  - `CMakeLists.txt`
  - `libc.cpp`
  - `ProjectA` (git submodule)

    - `CMakeLists.txt`
    - `liba.cpp`
  - `ProjectB` (git submodule)

    - `CMakeLists.txt`
    - `libb.cpp`
    - `ProjectA` (git submodule of the submodule `ProjectB`)

      - `CMakeLists.txt`
      - `liba.cpp`

And it has the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(C CXX)
add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
add_subdirectory(ProjectB)
add_library(c ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libc.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c a b)
```

Now if I try to run `cmake` for `ProjectC`, I get the following error.

```
add_library cannot create target "a" because another target with the same
name already exists....
```

I understand the reason of this error. It is because `ProjectA` is added as a subdirectory twice and all targets created by `add_library` is **Global**. For this particular case, I can fix it by remove `add_subdirectory(ProjectA)` in the `ProjectC/CMakeLists.txt`. However, consider a situation that `ProjectC` has many dependencies, and there might or might not be dependencies among them. From point of view of the developer of `ProjectC`, he should not need to care about the inter-dependencies among its own dependencies.

In this situation, what is the best way to have `ProjectC` include its dependencies? Having `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` as a git-submodule in source form is a must. I am aware that I can simply install `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` somewhere, and `ProjectC` only need to find the installed files somewhere. However, if possible, I would like to avoid that kind of solution (for example, if the installation was built with a different ABI than the one used by `ProjectC`, incompatibility issues arise). I would like all three projects to be built inside the build tree of `ProjectC`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a transitive dependency conflict using Git submodules and CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978414/how-to-handle-a-transitive-dependency-conflict-using-git-submodules-and-cmake)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check whether the target `a` already exists before calling `add_subdirectory`:

```
if (NOT TARGET a)
  add_subdirectory(ProjectA)
endif ()
```

so that it only adds the subdirectory once for your whole CMake project.

Comment: This answer, while sufficient for the question asked, has two major deficiencies:
1. It requires editing the external dependency, 2. it willnot work if C,B rely on two different versions of A.

The best practise for exporting libraries using CMake suggests prefixing target names with the project name, but this also runs into difficulties with versioning. If there were a way for the consumer to namespace external content that would be the best way but I have not been able to figure out if this is possible yet...