# How to clone multiple specific submodules?

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

I need to write a script to clone [Boost library](https://www.boost.org/), but the repository is unfortunately really big and I need to use just some submodules afterwards. I'd like to store them in one string variable like this

```
MODULES="tools/build libs/system"
```

and then pass the variable in to one command like this

```
git clone --recurse-submodules=${MODULES} https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
```

The problem is, that after passing multiple arguments into `--recurse-submodules`, all of them get ignored.

I had a look at [How to only update specific git submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728866/how-to-only-update-specific-git-submodules/31471460), but the answers cover only cloning of one submodules or repeating `--recurse-submodules` multiple times, which I don't like to, as I want to make the script prepared for arbitrary number of submodules.

Is there any way how to achieve that with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is right, but don't use a variable, use an array and build your sub-modules that way.

```
modules=()
for mod in "tools/build" "libs/system"; do
    modules+=( --recurse-submodules="$mod" )
done
```

In the `for` loop add all your modules names, so that each iteration adds the required fields before it and generates the complete sub-module array. Now pass it `git clone` as a quoted array expansion of `modules`

```
git clone "${modules[@]}" https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
```

The `"${modules[@]}"` expands to array generated in the step above, with each generated entry separated by a white-space character.

Comment: Out of curiosity... Is there any way to do this "purely" in CMake without Bash?

Comment: @Eenoku: I found couple of this links useful - https://foonathan.net/blog/2016/07/07/cmake-dependency-handling.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761594/cmake-and-using-git-submodule-for-dependence-projects. I'm not an expert in that, but your original post didin't refer to `CMake` at all. I answered it from a `bash` perspective. Ask a new question with `CMake` tag if you are interested and consider voting up this answer

Comment: Thank you! I know, that I've mentioned `Bash` and your answer is correct. Also I accepted it.

Comment: To be honest, accepting the answer is usually considered the proper reaction - I believe, that we shouldn't really "force" somebody to upvote our reactions.