# CMake how to avoid recursive add_subdirectory?

Tags: cmake

My workspace is structured as

```
workspace
  library1
  library2
  library3
```

`library3` depends on `library2` and `library1`

`library2` depends on `library1`

In `library3` CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)
add_subdirectory(../library2 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE}/../library2/build)
add_subdirectory(../library1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE}/../library1/build)
```

In `library2` CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.9)
add_subdirectory(../library1 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE}/../library1/build)
```

cmake in `library2` throws an error that `library1/build` already contains cmake files.

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/me/workspace/Library2/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_subdirectory):
  The binary directory

    C:/Users/me/workspace/Library1/build

  is already used to build a source directory.  It cannot be used to build
  source directory

    C:/Users/me/workspace/Library1

  Specify a unique binary directory name.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a transitive dependency conflict using Git submodules and CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978414/how-to-handle-a-transitive-dependency-conflict-using-git-submodules-and-cmake)

Comment: Collision of build directory is only the first problem with `add_subdirectory()` with same source directory. Even if you overcome it, you will face with double target's definition. Referenced question describes how to avoid latter problem, and it will help in avoiding the former one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How to setup Source, Library and CMakeLists.txt dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512485/cmake-how-to-setup-source-library-and-cmakelists-txt-dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

What I would personally do for something like this, is that in `workspace`, I have a root CMakeList.txt file that sets up the project:

```
# Set the minimum version of cmake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(library1)
add_subdirectory(library2)
add_subdirectory(library3)
```

(This is really all you need, your root CMakeLists.txt file doesn't need to be long at all).

And then instead of calling relative path `add_subdirectory()` calls, then for the libraries that require dependencies, use [`add_dependencies(<target> \[<target-dependency>\]...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_dependencies.html) to ensure that the dependency targets are built before the current target.

So inside of library3/CMakeLists.txt, after your `add_library/add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` calls (if applicable) add:

`add_dependencies(library3 general path/to/library2 general path/to/library1`

As an example.