# Handle cmake duplicated git subtrees

Tags: git, cmake, git-subtree

I have a cmake git repository with a library that I use in many project, named `core`.

I've another cmake git repository that includes `core` as dependency in a subtree. This project creates a library `plot`.

Now I have a new git repository that needs both `plot` and `core` as dependencies, and I've included them as subtrees as well. Now the structure of my project is:

```
myproject
|
|-Thirdparty-subtrees
  |
  |-core
  |-plot
    |
    |-Thirdparty-subtrees
      |
      |-core
```

Now when I want to build `myproject` with cmake it tells me that I've two project with the same name `core`, because the project is defined twice.

I can remove the first-level `core` subtree, but then it will became an hidden dependency, and if for some reason `plot` will erase the `core` subtree, I will have problems. I'd like to maintain the explicit dependency in the first level subtree folder.

So I'd like to know how can I check with CMake is two targets with the same name exists, and in this case notify it with a message and build only one project discarding the other (I suppose that if two targets have the same name, they are the same project).

How can I build `core` correctly only once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a transitive dependency conflict using Git submodules and CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978414/how-to-handle-a-transitive-dependency-conflict-using-git-submodules-and-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

As much as it may look like one, Git is not meant to be used as a dependency management tool. You are most likely better off using a different tool for this purpose.

Comment: I know. I want to know how to use CMake in order to include only once a project that's duplicated in my tree due to subtree management.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misunderstood the question. Apologies.